# Postgresql function return multiple select statements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Can any one of you tell me how to approach this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name()
  RETURNS ????? AS
$func$
BEGIN

 SELECT * FROM tbl_a a;

 SELECT * FROM tbl_b b;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Both tables have different structures.

Comment: This is not possible and it is also hard to imagine how it would be useful in a DBMS (which is good at manipulating lots of like data). Can you tell us why you want this?

Comment: @Patrick: if I had to guess: a migration from SQL Server to Postgres. This is pretty common in the SQL server world - at least I see this kind of problems also a lot when people migrate from SQL Server to Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are correct.we are migrating from SQl Server to postgres. So can you suggest me the best approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cursors but I can hardly imagine why you need such a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_multiselect(refcursor, refcursor) RETURNS VOID AS
  $func$
BEGIN
  OPEN $1 FOR SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines;
  OPEN $2 FOR SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

BEGIN;
SELECT my_multiselect('first_cursor_to_routines', 'second_cursor_to_sequences');
FETCH ALL IN first_cursor_to_routines;
FETCH ALL IN second_cursor_to_sequences;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're doing with this, but it sounds like you just want to return a union of these distinct result sets.  You can do this with a dynamic query.  I'm using Postgres 9.4.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_query(IN p_tables text[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_qry text;
    v_cols text;
    v_types text;
    v_as text;
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('
    WITH sub AS (
        SELECT 
            table_name, 
            column_name, 
            data_type 
        FROM 
            information_schema.columns 
        WHERE 
            table_name = ANY(%L)
        ORDER BY 
            table_name, 
            ordinal_position)
    ,sub2 AS(
        SELECT
            DISTINCT ON (column_name, data_type)
            column_name || '' '' || data_type AS def
        FROM
            sub
    )
    SELECT
        string_agg(def, '','')
    FROM
        sub2;
',
    p_tables
) INTO v_types;

v_qry := '
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name()
          RETURNS TABLE(' || v_types || ') AS
        $func$';

FOR i IN 1..array_upper(p_tables, 1)    
LOOP

    v_as := 'tbl' || i;

    EXECUTE format('
        WITH sub AS (
            SELECT 
                table_name, 
                column_name, 
                data_type 
            FROM 
                information_schema.columns 
            WHERE 
                table_name = ANY(%L)
            ORDER BY 
                table_name, 
                ordinal_position)
        ,sub2 AS(
            SELECT
                DISTINCT ON (column_name, data_type)
                CASE WHEN table_name = ''%I'' 
                    THEN %L || ''.'' || column_name 
                    ELSE ''NULL::'' || data_type 
                END AS cols
            FROM
                sub
        )
        SELECT
            string_agg(cols, '','')
        FROM
            sub2;
    ',
        p_tables,
        p_tables[i],
        v_as
    ) INTO v_cols;

    IF i > 1 THEN
        v_qry := v_qry || '
UNION ALL'; 
    END IF;

    v_qry := v_qry || '
SELECT ' || v_cols || ' FROM ' || p_tables[i] || ' AS ' || v_as;

    IF i = array_upper(p_tables, 1) THEN 
        v_qry := v_qry || ';'; 
    END IF;

END LOOP;
v_qry := v_qry || '
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
';

EXECUTE v_qry;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Sorry it looks ugly here, but this formatting helps the final product look nicer.  If you're shy about executing a dynamic query like this off the bat, just replace `EXECUTE v_qry;` with `RAISE INFO 'v_qry: %', v_qry;` and it will simply print the dynamic query out in a message without executing it, so you can review what it will do once executed.

Then execute make_query() with a list of tables you want to display like this:

```
SELECT make_query(ARRAY['tbl_a', 'tbl_b']);
```

The result is that you will now have a function called name() which you can call in order to see the results of both tables at the same time, with all the union details already sorted out:

```
SELECT * FROM name();
```